# Has Batman ever defeated Superman without kryptonite?

Tags: dc, batman, superman, dc-extended-universe

Batman always seems to surprise him with kryptonite.

Has he ever defeated Superman without it? By defeat I mean incapacitate, not just talk him around.

This [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/19956/3804) fails to list an instance of this (after asking,  Batman uses *kryptonite gum*, exactly the shenanigans I want to avoid). The [other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/83207/3804) doesn't mention how Batman defeats him.

All media is fine,  movies,  comics,  cartoons etc.

Magic is allowed.

Comment: IRTA as "decapitate" at first!!

Comment: [Does the box office count?](http://www.the-numbers.com/movies/franchises/)

Comment: Not batman himself but i remember that Alfred beat superman up pretty bad after consuming some sort of a "superpill" that lex engineered from Superman's DNA. It was pretty bad, Alfred ended the fight in the most badass way by saying "i'm very disappointed in you." before knocking him on the ground.

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: @AJL It's a prequel comic for *Injustice: Gods Among Us*. See [here](http://injusticegodsamongus.wikia.com/wiki/Alfred_Pennyworth) and [here](http://l7world.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Superman-VS-Alfred-Injustice-Gods-Among-Us-36.jpg?2ab298).

Comment: There are only three ways to defeat Superman: red sunlight (or lack of yellow sunlight), kryptonite, and magic. This kind of limits Batman's options.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Yes**

In the Red Son universe (Earth 30), the soviet Batman fought against Superman using Red Sun lamps, weakening Superman enough for him to beat him up.

However Wonder Woman, who was used as bait, was convinced by Superman to destroy the generator powering the lamps, which lead to Superman's powers returning and Batman killing himself (as this Superman lobotomizes his victims).

Edit: to clarify, exposed to kryptonite, kryptonians are harmed whilst red sun removes (temporarily) their powers, normally without them knowing.

Comment: Awesome! I had completely forgotten about Red Son

Comment: @AncientSwordRage most people do, it's a rare jewel in the multiverse

Comment: Russian Batman is best Batman

Comment: While technically right, using something other than kryptonite to do exactly what kryptonite does is kind of unsatisfying, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinCarney it is, but superman isn't weakened just power deprived, if it was zod or another military kryptonian they would be able to hold their own

Comment: In soviet Russia, man bats you.

Answer (score 11):

According to [Batman Wikia](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_(Earth-30)) Anarchistic Russian Terrorist Batman, defeats Soviet Weapon Superman (*briefly*) on Earth(30):

> Batman forges a temporary alliance with Lexcorp and with his parents'
>   killer to attempt a coup. He then kidnapped Superman's colleague and
>   friend Wonder Woman to use her as bait for Superman, in order to draw
>   him into a wasteland, where Batman was hoping to sap his powers with
>   rays that imitate the light of Superman's native sun.
>
> The plan worked, and Batman then bombarded Superman with simulated red
>   sunlight. But unfortunately for Batman, Wonder Woman breaks free and
>   rescues Superman by removing the generator powering the lamps,
>   although the process (which requires snapping her golden lasso)
>   seriously injures her.
>
> Batman commits suicide to avoid capture, but not before revealing to
>   Superman that Pyotr had a role in the plot. Then, unwilling to be
>   locked up, Batman instead detonated a bomb, and was killed in the
>   explosion.

Wonder Woman Escapes and "removes" the generator powering the lamps, needing no convincing from anyone.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Superman/Batman issue (Issue #78) that has them fighting and Batman Ultimately winning through blotting out the sun, though this was all just 2 kids talking about who would win. The issue does point out one of the most important things about this fight...

While Batman will likely die, he ultimately will win, because he has set up so many contingencies to handle the issue if it ever comes down to it. Dying and Losing is not the same thing is something that a lot of these battles don't take into account.

At the end Batman says "The kid had a lot of it right" and that he'd beat Superman without Kryptonite... whether this is a bluff or not...well, if he'd thought of blotting out the sun then it's not.

---

Another Batman/Superman fight is in Batman: HUSH. Batman does use kryptonite innefectively in the fight and ultimately wins in another way, rather than using the ring.

Comment: Alright I has done it and Good?

Comment: It's great thanks for editing

Comment: Hm - are you sure that's not how C. Montgomery Burns would beat Superman?